Annotate factory method in parent class that returns instances of subclasses
I'm trying to add type annotations to a factory method in a parent class that returns instances of subclasses:
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, param: int):
        if param > 0:
            return ChildA()
        else:
            return ChildB()

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass

According to my understanding, Self should be a valid type annotation for the return value of make. However, with typing_extension.Self (from typing_extensions 4.12.1, I'm on Python 3.8) Mypy 1.10.0 complains:
self_sandbox.py:7: error: Incompatible return value type (got "ChildA", expected "Self")  [return-value]
self_sandbox.py:9: error: Incompatible return value type (got "ChildB", expected "Self")  [return-value]

Since ChildA and ChildB are subclasses of Parent, I don't understand why this is happening. Note that Mypy does accept the following code:
param = 1
foo: Parent = ChildA() if param > 0 else ChildB()

In my understanding, this is is equivalent to make, type-wise.
Note that Parent works as a annotation for the return value of make, and that's the workaround I'm currently using. But I'd really prefer to use Self because it avoids duplicating the class name.
Is this an issue with Mypy or typing_extensions, or am I misunderstanding something?

Self is not correct. Because that means ChildA.make(...) will at least return a ChildA, but it does not, sometimes it returns ChildB

Hard-coding particular children in the definition of Parent couples the parent too closely to particular children. Just like an instance method that doesn't use self, a class method that doesn't use cls probably shouldn't be a class method.  make would seem to be better off as a static method, or even a standalone function.

@Wombatz To be fair, make doesn't seem to be intended to be called from any particular subclass, but from Parent itself. (It makes some sense to call Parent.make without knowing or caring which subclass it will return, but it wouldn't make any real sense to call ChildA.make(5) to get an instance of ChildB)

@chepner that's true, but that it the exact reason why mypy forbids that, right? If make could not be called from any other class then Self would be correct, i believe

RIght. Given that I don't really recommend this kind of factory being a class method in the first place, though, don't take my assertion that Self is "correct" too strongly :)

@Wombatz: You're comment regarding the return type of ChildA.make is what I was missing. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Self is not the correct annotation for make() here. It might seem so, if you only look at Parent.make()
Technically it is possible to call ChildA.make() (even though you don't plan on doing it). The Self now tells us that ChildA.make() returns a ChildA (or one of its subclasses) but actually the implementation return a ChildB sometimes. That's why the type hint Self cannot be correct.
You have to duplicate the parent class name here. But it's the correct thing to do
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, param: int) -> 'Parent':
        if param > 0:
            return ChildA()
        else:
            return ChildB()

